# Maximize the difference of the sum of picked numbers by 2 players

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, greedy

I have 2 problems that derive from a simple problem. I'll explain the simple one with the solution I found and after that the modified problem.

> Suppose there is a game with 2 players, A and B and a list of
>   positive integers. Player A starts by taking out a number from the list, player
>   B does the same and so on after the there are no longer numbers in the
>   list. Both players sum up the picked numbers. The goal
>   for each player is to maximize the difference between his sum and
>   opponent's sum, which is the score. The question is what is the
>   maximum score player A can obtain if both players play in an optimal
>   manner.

Now, for this I figured out that the optimal strategy for each player is to take the biggest number at each step, the pseudocode is the following:

```
sumA = 0
sumB = 0
list = [1, 5, 3, 7, 9]

while list IS NOT EMPTY:
    val = pop_max(list)
    sumA = sumA + val

    if list IS NOT EMPTY:
        val = pop_max(list)
        sumB = sumB + val


scoreA = sumA - sumB
print scoreA
```

This can run in **O(n)** or **O(n*log(n))** depending how the numbers from list are sorted.

The following 2 modification:

> At the beginning of the game player A should remove K numbers from the list. If he does this in an optimal manner and after that the games is the initial one, what is the maxim score he can obtain?

and

> At each step the players can pick the left-most or the right-most number from the list. Again they play in an optimal manner. Which is the maximum score player A can obtain?

For the second modification I can think of a brute-force approach, i.e. computing the tree of all possibilities, but this does not work for big input data. I believe that there is some kind of DP algorithm.

For the first modification I can't think of an idea.

Can someone help with some algorithm ideas for the 2 modifications?

[LATTER EDIT]

The solution for the 2nd modification can be found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optimal-strategy-for-a-game-dp-31/ It is DP.

Comment: If you speak french (or can translate it) the first exercise of this exam looks like your last problem (solution is given page 5) : https://xtof-durr.github.io/ALG/examens/examen_2018.pdf
The main difference is they can take as many number they want from the left or right. But all Bellman equations are given.

Comment: The maximum score surely depends on *which* numbers are in the list. But yes, generally, choosing the biggest number available at each step is optimal play, and in all versions is an optimal strategy for player 1 and it is a winning strategy (if such a strategy exists given the numbers in play)

Comment: I found the solution for the 2nd variation for the first problem at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optimal-strategy-for-a-game-dp-31/

Comment: In the first modification, is `k` fixed at the beginning or it has to be computed?

Comment: @pLOPeGG it is fixed and given as an input to the algorithm.

Comment: Actually you are not opmitimizing the difference but the sum. If both players would maximize the difference one player would take the large numbers and the other one the small numbers.

Comment: The first modification is very simple, if you just optimize the sum of player A, then you will have to remove the K smallest numbers or player B will be taking away higher numbers from you and the sum will become smaller.

Comment: @maraca Not really, from what you've told, the both players would work for the same goal. But they are opponents. Suppose at the end of the game player A has ```sumA``` and player B has ```sumB```, with ```sumA > sumB```. The score of the player A ```scoreA = sumA - sumB``` which is positive and the score of the player B ```scoreB = sumB - sumA```. Which is negative. Every player wants to maximazi its score. Its natural for player B to be as close as possible to player A. Does it make sense?

Comment: @maraca If the score of player A is ```A > 0``` then the score of B is ```B = -A```. Look at it like this, player A wants to make ```A``` as big as possible and player B as small as possible. They both play in an optimal manner.

Comment: The first modification can be solved by looking at the differences of the ordered set. The point is that in the sequence { d0, d1, d2,...} where dx = list[x+1] - list[x] player A only needs to look at every other dx to tell whether this is optimal. Eliminating a number x is the same as adding d[x] to d[x+1] and then recalculating the achievable difference. I think this is doable with standard dynamic programming. I'll see if I can post a program later.

Comment: @Vroomfondel so you mean eliminating those numbers who give have the smallest difference between neighbours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the post for the 2nd modification, which is

> At each step the players can pick the left-most or the right-most number from the list. Again they play in an optimal manner. Which is the maximum score player A can obtain?

The solution is based on DP. For the sub-problem (i-j) i.e. `v[]i, v[i+1], ..., v[j]` there are two choices:

1. The user chooses the i-th element with value v[i]: The opponent either chooses (i+1)-th element or j-th element. The opponent intends to choose the element which leaves the user with minimum value. i.e. The user can collect the value `v[i] + min(F(i+2, j), F(i+1, j-1))`

[image]

2. The user chooses the j-th element with value v[j]: The opponent either chooses i-th element or (j-1)-th element. The opponent intends to choose the element which leaves the user with minimum value.
   i.e. The user can collect the value `v[j] + min(F(i+1, j-1), F(i, j-2))`

[image]

Following is recursive solution that is based on above two choices. We take the maximum of two choices.

> F(i, j) represents the maximum value the user can collect from i-th coin to j-th coin.
>
> F(i, j) = Max(v[i] + min(F(i+2, j), F(i+1, j-1)), v[j] + min(F(i+1, j-1), F(i, j-2)))
>
> Base Cases
>
> F(i, j)  = v[i] If j == i
>
> F(i, j)  = max(v[i], v[j])  If j == i+1

Here is a pice of code in Python that solves it

```
def optimalStrategyOfGame(arr, n): 
  
    # Create a table to store solutions of subproblems  
    table = [[0 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)] 

    # Fill table using above recursive formula. Note that the table is  
    # filled in diagonal fashion from diagonal elements to table[0][n-1] which is the result.  
    for gap in range(n): 
        for j in range(gap, n): 
            i = j - gap 
          
            # Here x is value of F(i+2, j), y is F(i+1, j-1) and z is  
            # F(i, j-2) in above recursive formula  
            x = 0
            if((i + 2) <= j): 
                x = table[i + 2][j] 
            y = 0
            if((i + 1) <= (j - 1)): 
                y = table[i + 1][j - 1] 
            z = 0
            if(i <= (j - 2)): 
                z = table[i][j - 2] 
            table[i][j] = max(arr[i] + min(x, y), arr[j] + min(y, z)) 
    return table[0][n - 1]
```

[SOURCE] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optimal-strategy-for-a-game-dp-31/